# conflict with min parsley.js and min html5 input type date

Tags: html, date, input, types, parsley.js

crome send this code

parsley.js:363 Uncaught Requirement is not a number: "2016-07-28"

Comment: <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                     <input class="form-control" type="date" id="fllegada" required data-parsley-required-message="Indica Fecha de Llegada" data-parsley-errors-container="#e1" min="2016-07-28">
                     </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it's a [known issue](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/814) that noone has fixed yet

Comment: thaks, I decide to turn off parsley validation for <input type date> so its works for me